# Loop function PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, loops, insert, pg

I'd like to create a function that puts 100 random values into a table.

I have something like that but I get message:

ERROR: syntax error near "end"
LINE 16: end loop;
SQL state: 42601
Character: 530

The code snippet with Insert when invoked by hand works fine. Any ideas?

```
do
$do$
declare
     i int;
begin
for  i in 1..100
loop
            Insert into "TS".meetings
                    VALUES(
                            (Select  max("ID")+1 from "TS".meetings)
                           ,(Select public.random_between(1,(Select max(pid) from "TS".persons where departmentid in (1,7,8,9))))
                           ,(Select now()+(random()*20)*'1 day'::interval)
                           ,(Select "City" from "TS".city where id = (Select public.random_between(1,(Select max(id) from "TS".city ))))
                           ,(Select public.random_between(1,(Select max(id) from "TS".klienci )))
                    )
end loop;
end;
$do$;
```

Comment: You are missing `;` at end of query

Comment: FYI, you don't need to `DECLARE i`. See here [Loops](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS)  42.6.5.5. FOR (Integer Variant) "... The variable name is automatically defined as type integer and exists only inside the loop (any existing definition of the variable name is ignored within the loop) ..."

Comment: No need for a loop or PL/pgSQL you can use `insert into .. select ... from generate_series(1,100)`